# Preg_match doesn't find accents

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to search a word with accents or spanish characters but it doesn't work

```
if(preg_match('|\b(' . $iText . ')\b|i', $str_content)) {...}
```

For example if i insert

```
$iText="desempeño";
```

or

```
$iText="Función necesaria"
```

and it doesn't work, of course, i post $iText with a form input.

--------------EDIT--------

Well i solved with a array replacing normal characters to ASCII characters:

```
function prepare($pattern)
{
$replacements =array('À'=>'&Agrave;', 'à'=>'&agrave;', 'Á'=>'&Aacute;', 'á'=>'&aacute;', 'Â'=>'&Acirc;', 'â'=>'&acirc;', 'Ã'=>'&Atilde;', 'ã'=>'&atilde;', 'Ä'=>'&Auml;', 'ä'=>'&auml;', 'Å'=>'&Aring;', 'å'=>'&aring;', 'Æ'=>'&AElig;', 'æ'=>'&aelig;', 'Ç'=>'&Ccedil;', 'ç'=>'&ccedil;', 'Ð'=>'&ETH;', 'ð'=>'&eth;', 'È'=>'&Egrave;', 'è'=>'&egrave;', 'É'=>'&Eacute;', 'é'=>'&eacute;', 'Ê'=>'&Ecirc;', 'ê'=>'&ecirc;', 'Ë'=>'&Euml;', 'ë'=>'&euml;', 'Ì'=>'&Igrave;', 'ì'=>'&igrave;', 'Í'=>'&Iacute;', 'í'=>'&iacute;', 'Î'=>'&Icirc;', 'î'=>'&icirc;', 'Ï'=>'&Iuml;', 'ï'=>'&iuml;', 'Ñ'=>'&Ntilde;', 'ñ'=>'&ntilde;', 'Ò'=>'&Ograve;', 'ò'=>'&ograve;', 'Ó'=>'&Oacute;', 'ó'=>'&oacute;', 'Ô'=>'&Ocirc;', 'ô'=>'&ocirc;', 'Õ'=>'&Otilde;', 'õ'=>'&otilde;', 'Ö'=>'&Ouml;', 'ö'=>'&ouml;', 'Ø'=>'&Oslash;', 'ø'=>'&oslash;', 'Œ'=>'&OElig;', 'œ'=>'&oelig;', 'ß'=>'&szlig;', 'Þ'=>'&THORN;', 'þ'=>'&thorn;', 'Ù'=>'&Ugrave;', 'ù'=>'&ugrave;', 'Ú'=>'&Uacute;', 'ú'=>'&uacute;', 'Û'=>'&Ucirc;', 'û'=>'&ucirc;', 'Ü'=>'&Uuml;', 'ü'=>'&uuml;', 'Ý'=>'&Yacute;', 'ý'=>'&yacute;', 'Ÿ'=>'&Yuml;', 'ÿ'=>'&yuml;');
 return str_replace(array_keys($replacements), $replacements, $pattern);  
}
```

then i put this function in the if :

```
 if(preg_match('|\b(' . prepare($iText) . ')\b|i', prepare($str_content)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `u (PCRE_UTF8)` modifier to your regular expression

> u (PCRE_UTF8) This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE
> that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8.
> This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from
> PHP 4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern is checked since PHP
> 4.3.5.

[`Source`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Just add it like this..

```
if(preg_match('|\b(' . $iText . ')\b|ui', $str_content)) {...}
                                     ^--- Here
```

Comment: Thank you, but forgive my ignorance, i've looking how add that but i don't undestand, can you give more details?
Thanks again

Comment: Still not working... Give me not results foreach ($aObj[$i] as $key=>$ee)
    {
      $str_content = $ee->plaintext;
   if(preg_match('|\b(' . $iText . ')\b|ui', $str_content))
{

Comment: That should actually work.. Can you try this ? `if(preg_match('|\b(\p{L}' . $iText . ')\b|ui', $str_content)) {...}`

Comment: Not working for me. but well i just solved, i will show in a edit

Comment: Instead you can edit this answer or add a new answer on your own. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks bro. I put my solution in the first post
THanks for all

Comment: @Snickfire, Sadly, that's not an ideal solution btw  :(

Comment: What do you mean... will bring me problems?

Comment: What does `$str_content` hold actually ? Can you post the output of it ?

Comment: It contains many texts between <div class="content"> from many static html sites. I extract it with file_get_html of simple_html_dom class. It's a kind search with static html sites without database, of course

$array = array("file1.html","file2.html"....);

for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
 $html[$i] = file_get_html($array[$i]);}
    // get text elements
 for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
  $aObj[$i] = $html[$i]->find('div[class="contenido"]');
 }for($i=0; $i<count($aObj); $i++){foreach ($aObj[$i] as $key=>$ee){$str_content = $ee->plaintext;
{ The output it's just text from many html pages